# Generate random string with capital letters and numbers without O and 0

Tags: javascript, string, random

I'm wanting to generate a random string with a length of 12 with capital letters only and numbers with no letter O or the number 0 in javascript. here is what I have:

```
Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 12)
```

but the problem is that it is not all capital and i don't want the letter O or the number 0. thanks

Comment: Perhaps an smaller, more manageable problem you should solve, is how would you randomly generate a single character with those conditions? Then just do it 12 times.

Comment: You should also consider s,5,l,1,I as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function rand_str_without_O0() {
    const list = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
    var res = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        res = res + list.charAt(rnd);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Usage:

```
var randomString = rand_str_without_O0();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let foo = function(length) { //length should be <= 7
  return  Math.random().toString(36).toUpperCase().replace(/[0-9O]/g, '').substring(1,length+1)
}

response = foo(6) + foo(6)
```

This will first generate random string convert to uppercase, then remove the un-needed values and then create substring of required length. As far as I have seen, this will generate a string of at-least 7 characters so you can use it twice to generate string of length 12.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick solution and probably not optimal.

```
var myString = function(len, excluded) {
  var included = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

  // remove the excluded chars from the included string
  for (var i = 0; i < excluded.length; i++) {
    included = included.split(excluded[i]).join('');
  }

  // add len random chars form whatever is left.
  var output = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    output += included.charAt(Math.random() * included.length);
  }

  return output;
}
```

And you call it with the desired length and an array of characters to exclude:

```
console.log(myString(12, ['0', 'O']));
```

EDIT: This solution allows the output length and the chars to be excluded to be passed on as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
var all_chars_without_O0 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789'.split('');

// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function pickRandom(arr) {
  return arr[getRandomInt(0, arr.length)];
}

function randomString(length = 12, chars = all_chars_without_O0) {
  var s = '';
  while (length--)
    s += pickRandom(chars);
  return s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MrQubo/fusb1746/1/

Or using lodash:

```
var all_chars_without_O0 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789'.split('');

function randomString(length = 12, chars = all_chars_without_O0) {
  return _.sampleSize(chars, length).join('');
}
```

However, you should be warned, that `Math.random()` doesn't provide cryptographically secure random numbers. See [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) for more information.